# Highstock flags series title gets mixed up when setting extremes

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock setExtremes to replace flags on a series. Take note of the dates and tooltip text when hovering over the max and min flags.

Move the range slider and notice that the title of the max and min flags get mixed up. This may take a little bit of moving the slider to see this happen. You will then see the min flag tooltip display: "new max" and the max flag tooltip will display "new min".

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/mobijay/q7djqypa/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {

          updateDataSummary(e.min, e.max);
        }
      }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'USD to EUR',
      data: usdeur,
      id: 'dataseries'
    }, {
      type: 'flags',
      onSeries: 'dataseries',
      name: 'Updated Flags',
      data: [{
        title: 'max',
        text: 'original max',
        x: Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1)
      }, {
        title: 'min',
        text: 'original min',
        x: Date.UTC(2015, 6, 12)
      }]
    }]
  });
});

function updateDataSummary(min, max) {
  var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
  console.log(chart.series[1].name);
  var minMaxSeries = {
    type: 'flags',
    onSeries: 'dataseries',
    name: 'work',
    data: [{
      title: 'max',
      text: 'new max',
      x: Date.UTC(2015, 5, 12)
    }, {
      title: 'min',
      text: 'new min',
      x: Date.UTC(2015, 5, 1)
    }]
  };
  chart.series[1].setData(minMaxSeries.data, false);
  chart.redraw();
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<div id="report" style="font: 0.8em sans-serif"></div>
```

Comment: I think that you can remove your series and add it again with new values, this should help you with this problem. https://jsfiddle.net/q7djqypa/17/
You have also problems with sorting your data. Highcharts expects your data to be in increasing order. You can also try adding your data with update() method. https://jsfiddle.net/q7djqypa/18/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thank you so much, the update option works very well!